# the paragraph of a file is not showing according to url in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have a probem with routes in ReactJS.
I want to show the AddUser file which looks like this:

```
const AddUser = () => {
    return(
        <p>Hello from Add User</p>
    )
}
export default AddUser;
```

but when I press http://localhost:3000/add, the 'Hello from Add User' is not shown.

What is the problem?

---

file which looks like this

[image]

Comment: have you implemented react router dom, put that code here please Era

Comment: yes Ashish, i implemented like this - npm i react-router-dom

Comment: Please dont add pictures of code, you can just copy paste it.

Comment: @kevin since it is a basic code, i dont think there is any problem about the pic

Comment: If i want to reproduce your error in a sandbox i cant copy your code. So it is a bit of a problem. Or for example if i want to copy the code into my answer i will have to type it over.

Comment: @kevin good idea , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple example of react routing dom implementation, with url changes it will rendered on screen,
import this,

```
import { HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component= { (props) => ( <div>Home</div> )} />
      <Route path="/add" component={(props) => ( <AddUser  /> )} />     
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

then you need a button,

```
<button className="btn">
    <a href="/add">Add</a>
</button>
```

in your case,

```
const AddUser = () => {
    return(
        <p>Hello from Add User</p>
    )
}
```

Comment: Still it is not working, the paragraphs are not shown yet